# how to match everything except a particular pattern using regex

Tags: regex

After a half hour searching I failed. Now I am trying to match everything except the given word.

I am trying to match `/user/*` except one word `login`.

Examples:

```
/user/test  match!
/user/loginno match!
/user/login  not match!
```

My regex is：`^/user/(?!login)(.*)` but I can not make `/user/loginno` match ):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^/user/(?!login\b)(.*)`

I altered your regex by requiring there to be a word boundary after login for the lookahead to match, e.g. login followed by a non alphanumerical character (space or / for example). It seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\/user\/(?!login\b)(.*)
```

This is the corrected regex after escaping forward slashes

Comment: Why would you escape forward slashes?

Comment: some compiler doesn't allow it

Comment: Given that the OP's regex compiles, and it does not have the forward slashes escaped, either the OP knows about when forward slashes need to be escaped or doesn't need to do it in this case.